# How to set collapseProperties in an Ant build file for Closure Compiler?

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I've seen some reference to a `collapseProperties` option when compiling with the Google Closure Compiler, but I don't understand how to set it in an Ant build file.

Will someone please provide an example? Or some documentation that has examples?

Also, if I'm compiling with `compilationLevel="advanced"`, is `collapseProperties` already `true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"collapseProperties" is one of standard optimization passes enabled in ADVANCED mode.  It is not available as a separate command-line option or as part of the ANT support that is part of the compiler's source tree. It is configurable using the Java API, should you wish to change it.

It basically attempts to remove objects used as namespaces, simplifying further analysis and making additional optimization possible.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using advanced mode collapsed is true by default.